# JavaFx Create a Scene within a Pane

Tags: java, javafx, graphics

I have a 2D GUI declared in an FXML file. The GUI contains a pane, I want to make a 3D scene within the pane. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`SubScene`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html), which, like a `Scene` has a camera, depth buffering, etc.